# get all with same name and value in tuple using named tuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

In python namedtuple, how can I get all values with the same name?

eg. : `[tup(a = 1, b=2), tup(a = 2, b=5), tup(a = 3, b=2)]`

How can I get all a's or all b's?

Also, is it possible to get all tuples with `b == 2` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List comprehensions for the win:

```
all_b_values = [t.b for t in list_of_named_tuples]
all_a_values = [t.a for t in list_of_named_tuples]
```

or

```
all_b_2s = [t for t in list_of_named_tuples if t.b == 2]
```

There is nothing `namedtuple`-specific about these list comprehensions; they work for any sequence of objects with common attributes.